# Delphi Json TreeView DataSet

Tags: json, delphi, treeview

Ainda não ví nada parecido aqui,

No Delphi a select no `dataset` retorna os dados para minha arvore dessa forma:

```
ID  PARENT      NOME          
1   null        GrandFather1    
2   1           Son1            
4   2           GrandSon1       
5   2           GrandSon2       
3   1           Son2
6   null        GrandFather2
```

Gostaria de Montar meu `Json`, assim:

```
[
    {
        text: 'GrandFather1',
        href: '#1',
        nodes: [
            {
                text: 'Son1',
                href: '#2',
                nodes: [
                    {
                        text: 'GrandSon1',
                        href: '#4'
                    },
                    {
                        text: 'GrandSon2',
                        href: '#5'
                    }
                ]
            },
            {
                text: 'Son2',
                href: '#3'
            }
        ]
    },
    {
        text: 'GrandFather2',
        href: '#6'
    }
]
```

Vou usar no [https://jonmiles.github.io/bootstrap-treeview/]

Confesso que estou apanhando, tentei usar os recursos do `System.JSON`, mas não consegui uma lógica para isso.